# How can I set up a foriegn key field given an attribute rather than the foriegn key id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and I'm having difficulties setting up my associations with my tables. I have a `Team` table that I want to have a foreign key to a `TeamType` table. The team type that I want to give each team is based on input from a form. Right now, my code is setup so that the user inputs the id of the team type. However, I want to make it so that the user inputs the name of the team type rather than the id in the form. With the name rather than the id, can I still populate the foreign id column? How could I do this? 
Here are my migrations:

```
class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.references :team_type, foreign_key: true
      t.string :team_name
      t.integer :num_of_students

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CreateTeamTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :team_types do |t|
      t.string :type_name
      t.integer :max_size

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here are my models:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  validates :team_name, length: {maximum: 40}, presence: true
  belongs_to :team_type
  # add_index :team_name
end
```

```
class TeamType < ApplicationRecord
  validates :type_name, length: {maximum: 35}, presence: true
  validates :max_size, numericality: { only_integer: true },
                       presence: true
end
```

Here is the create method of the team controller

```
  def create
    @team = Team.new(team_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @team.save
        format.html { redirect_to @team, notice: 'Team was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @team }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @team.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you already have several TeamTypes saved in the database, you can use a select in your form so the user can choose one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set up your form fields on the front end so that the options display the name, but also pass along the ID so objects can be associated. I'd recommend referencing the Rails docs about form helpers, specifically section 3.1 on Select and Option Tags: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags